# Chrome reports 2 different SSL padlock states for same site from different computers, possible infection?

Tags: android, google-chrome, ssl, https

This is a doozy. Will try and make it short and sweet.

Hitting the same web URL, my desktop computer reports SSL errors for many sites. HTTPS with a red line strike through and red padlocks in descriptions.

My mobile phone does not, on wifi or mobile network. My remote computer in a remote location does not. Green padlocks for all.

Chrome browser is up to date and latest (Version 47.0.2526.106 m) across all browsers. Extensions are identical across local and remote desktop.

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is loading up on my desktop at home that isn't loading up on my remote desktop at my moms. Both machines are on Win7 64 bit. Both chrome browsers are same version, same extensions running. Recently 'reset' chrome on my home desktop to try and fix. Worked first time, but problem came back. Second time it didn't do anything. Very random. Somedays i'll get green padlocks, somedays i get red ones. The intermittent nature of this has me dumbfounded. Also, all of the browsers actually state the info about an obsolete cipher, but only my desktop deems it to be redlock worthy. It also claims there are other insecure resources on the page, but my remote desktop and mobile device don't see them. wth?!?!

Should i completely remove chrome and reinstall it from scratch? Since i already used the 'Restore settings to their original defaults.' button in the settings.. this doesn't seem like it would cure it.

One other aspect i haven't been able to determine is whether my computer being hardwired into a TL-WPA4220 WiFi Powerline Extender is the culprit. Does the fact the extender/repeater not a direct connection to my router have anything to do with this? Altho my mobile phone is connected to that wifi access point and it shows a green padlock on the same sites so....

I am currently running a virus scan as we speak.

Any guesses? Thanks in advance.

Attached pics.
[home desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7M1v.jpg) | [remote desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXafN.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after thinking long and hard about the differences between computers. Ultimately i realized that all the working browsers were either fresh installs, or browsers that didn't have my user account connected and synced through it.

I ultimately went to Settings > Sign In / Disconnect your Google Account... and made sure all cookies/data for the local device were removed. Then i did a full browser 'Reset'.

Once i had the default standard page asking me to sign it, i tested the offending page. It showed up with a green padlock. I tested other offending bank sites as well. All green.

From there i closed the browser and restarted it, and when presented with the page to log into my google account, it resynced all my bookmarks/toolbars/extensions.

And still all green padlocks. Hopefully this is a permanent fix but for now it's all holding well. I also got slightly more updated to Chrome Version 47.0.2526.111 m.

My assumption here is that somewhere between the time i first synced my chrome to my google account years ago on this computer, whatever version it was then (42,45,who knows) that one of the updates to chrome didn't take well on my desktop and was creating conflicts only on this computer under this local profile. No amount of clearing cookies or resetting the browser could fix it. Fully disconnecting my account and re-syncing my chrome to my google account is what fixed the HTTPS / SSL padlock problems.

Not sure if this will help anyone, seems i was the only one on the internet with this problem. :P

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the dialog at the home desktop closely you will see

> connection is not private because the site loaded an insecure script

Since you don't see the message at the remote desktop it is very likely that a locally installed browser extension causes this problem. Thus check your extension, disable them and retry.

Comment: Hi Steffen, sorry about that message fragment. Thanks for that quick reply.

I figured it out after thinking long and hard about the differences between computers. Ultimately i realized that all the working browsers were either fresh installs, or browsers that didn't have my user account connected and synced through it.

I ultimately went to Settings > Sign In / Disconnect your Google Account... and made sure all cookies/data for the local device were removed. Then i did a full browser 'Reset'.

Once i had the default standard page asking me to sign it, i tested the offending page. All good.